# Как захватить переменное количество аргументов лямбдой?

Tags: c++

Как захватить переменное количество аргументов лямбдой?

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
auto lambda = [](){}; // как захватить args?
}
```

Comment: Опишите свой вопрос подробнее, добавьте детали, имеющийся код. В данный момент понять суть вопроса сложно.

Comment: @Komdosh добавил

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду склонировать аргументы?

Comment: @nick_n_a я имею в виду "захватить" (capture), не знаю что такое "склонировать"

Comment: Покажите более наглядно, что вы имеете ввиду, желательно с примером.

Comment: @nick_n_a вы просите меня показать, как сделать то, о чём я спрашиваю)?

Comment: Напишите так, как вы хотели бы, чтобы это работало, при этом данный код может не компилиться, но мы хотя бы поймём, что вы хотите сделать с переменными

Comment: Как вариант - можно показать, какие у вас данные на входе, и какие должны получится на выходе. Тогда мы поймём что имеется ввиду под словом захватить.

Comment: уже нашёл ответ по вопросу слово слово https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527595/how-to-capture-variable-number-of-arguments-in-lambda-function, в следующий раз спрошу на enSO

Comment: По мне нормальный вопрос, и стоило бы пытаться отвечать или ждать верного ответа... Автору вопроса советую просто хорошо изучать тему лямбда выражений.  Тогда не возникнут такие вопросы

Comment: "в следующий раз спрошу на enSO" - конечно спросите, если думаете, что там более лояльно относятся к низкокачественным вопросам, то вас скорее ожидает разочарование,

Comment: @0xdb,  можно узнать  чем вопрос низкокачественный? Человек не знает и спрашивает. Для того и существует SO

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Указал при закрытии, там же имеется ссылка на справку.

Comment: @0xdb, я не вижу ни одного пункта для правки. В вопросе кратко и ясно описано в чем проблема, что нужно получать и пример приведен.  Нужно проявлять  больше желания помочь (если можете), чем критиковать.  Повторюсь, вопрос вполне нормальный

Comment: @ARHovsepyan "и пример приведен" - извините, где вы его там нашли в первой редакции? Посмотрите  [timeline](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/914787/timeline).